# Access to all information of tables from pivot table Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I hope somebody help with this, regards, i have a pivot table what have this fields what is only ids of the other tables Companies, Branchs, Departments, Jobs, Employes

```
'id',
'company_id',
'branch_id',
'department_id',
'job_id',
'employee_id'
```

I want to access to all information when i consult one only register i want to use withPivot() but i dont understand what need to do i already have this in model Company.php

```
public function getAllInformation()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Company::class, 'companies_branches_departments_jobs_employes', 'id', 'company_id');
}
```

And in the controller i have this

```
public function index()
{
    $items = Company::with('getAllInformation')->limit(1)->get();
    $information =
        [
            'items' => $items,
            'total' => count($items)
        ];
    return $information;
}
```

This give me the information of the first Company with the information in the function getAllInformation but i want all of the all

Before i have this in the Model CompaniesBranchesDepartmentsJobsEmployes.php

```
    public function company()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Company::class, 'id', 'company_id');
}

public function branch()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Branch::class, 'id', 'branch_id');
}

public function department()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Department::class, 'id', 'department_id');
}

public function job()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Job::class, 'id', 'job_id');
}

public function employee()
{
    return $this->hasOne(Employe::class, 'id', 'employee_id');
}
```

And in the Controller this

```
    public function getAllInformation()
{
    $items = CompaniesBranchesDepartmentsJobsEmployes::with('company', 'branch', 'department', 'job', 'employee')->limit(10)->get();
    $inventory =
        [
            'items' => $items,
            'total' => count($items)
        ];
    return $inventory;
}
```

This give me a Json of all information and is fine but i want to use pivot functions because is the right way of laravel for work with table pivot, i need to make a array for all the information in the var $items or what, any help thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

You can define $with array in you model.

Example

```
class Company extends Model {
    $with = [
      'company',
      'branch',
       ...etc
    ];
}
```

And than just call

```
Company:limit(1)->get();
```

Comment: mmmmm interesting, i will try that :D

Comment: Thanks curious to know the results of the try, if it helped.